# validate bean constraint on manufacturer property sometimes based on configuration from data base

Tags: spring, hibernate, bean-validation, hibernate-validator, spring-validator

Can we achieve @NotNull constraint gets executed only if it is enabled to execute in DB

```
public class Vehicle {
  @NotNull //supposed to execute only if configuration in database is enable to execute this @Notnull annotation
  private String manufacturer;  
  private String id;
}
```

Comment: This is a... peculiar requirement. You can [implement a custom constraint](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.1/reference/en-US/html/validator-customconstraints.html#validator-customconstraints-simple), injecting the `EntityManager` (or any other bean) into the validator. I'm curious why you would need such a feature, though

Comment: thanks @crizzis. Requirement: I have lot of dtos which are having certain properties and few of those properties are optional for some countries and for few countries those properties are mandatory.

Comment: I can not use custom constraint as i have to implement for each and every constraint. so check with community whether i can leverage some feature which i am not aware of

Comment: the point here is if validation is disable i don't want to execute subsequent annotation constraints

Comment: I turned my comment into an answer, please have a look

Answer (score 0):

> I can not use custom constraint as i have to implement for each and every constraint. so check with community whether i can leverage some feature which i am not aware of

Why not implement a custom constraint that will validate all of those optional validation rules? Just use a class-level constraint rather than a field-level constraint. It would look sth like this:

```
@FieldsRequiredForSpecialCountries // inside, use @Target(TYPE) instead of @Target(FIELD)
public class Vehicle {...}

class FieldsRequiredForSpecialCountriesValidator implements ConstraintValidator<FieldsRequiredForSpecialCountries, Vehicle> {
    // constructor etc.

    @Autowired
    private CountryRepository repository;

    public void validate(Vehicle input, ConstraintValidationContext context) {
        if (input != null && repository.isSpecialCountry(input.getCountry()) {
            if (Objects.isEmpty(input.getManufacturer()) {
                context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation()
                    .buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("must not be empty")
                    .addPropertyNode("manufacturer")
                    .addConstraintViolation();
                return false;
            }
            ... // the rest of the rules, you could also collect all the rules first instead of immediately returning when a violation is found
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

The only alternative I can think of is using [constraint groups](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkagv.html):

```
public interface SpecialCountriesOnly {}

public class Vehicle {

    @NotNull(groups = SpecialCountriesOnly.class)
    private String manufacturer;
}
```

To use it, though, you would have to either:

1. Invoke the validator programatically, with the correct groups depending on the country:

```
@Autowired
private Validator validator;
...

if (countryRepository.isSpecialCountry(vehicle.getCountry()) {
    var constraintViolations = validator.validate(vehicle, javax.validation.groups.Default.class, SpecialCountriesOnly.class);
    ... // do sth with the violations, e.g. wrap in `ConstraintViolationException`)
} else {
    var constraintViolations = validator.validate(vehicle); // only the default group is validated here
    ...
}
```

2. Keep the declarative approach and instead expose separate service/controller methods for 'special' and regular countries:

```
public void saveRegularCountryVehicle(@Validated @IsRegularCountry Vehicle vehicle) {
    ...
}

public void saveSpecialCountryVehicle(@Validated({{Default.class, SpecialCountriesOnly.class}) @IsSpecialCountry Vehicle vehicle) {
    
}
```